# How to capture keypress in View added by WindowManager

Tags: android, events, view, window, key

I would like to add a custom view for my application. For this I use WindowsManager:

```
        final WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
        final View view = ((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.game_menu, null);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        lp.dimAmount = (float) 0.6;
        lp.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
        lp.windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Dialog;
        view.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
            {
                Log.d("12", "12");
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                {
                    wm.removeView(view); // This I need to hide my menu
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        wm.addView(view, lp); // I add menu like in Angry Birds and other games
```

But I cannot capture device key events for hiding this view.

Why my key listener not invoked in view added by WindowsManager? What must I do to hide my view by device back key pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views, which added by windows manager not receive onKey event due to android safety politics.

Comment: Instead of adding view with WindowManager, I use Relativelayout.addView(); to add menu view to activity.

Comment: @Nik but i am adding view in Service. How to handle this?

Comment: @rup35h I think, it is not possible to listen keys event in view added thru WindowManager due to security restrictions. Otherwise any app could add transparent view and listen user input in any application! You may start activity with transparent background and do any actions in this activity.

Comment: Then how does facebook messenger allow you to close the popup messenger view when you press the back key? This is possible, maybe by overriding dispatchKeyEvent in a view that is added to the window manager.

Comment: @Eshaan why are you think that facebook messenger adds view thru window manager? It may show it from activity or dialog window. But I have not using facebook messenger and I can't say for sure.

Comment: if you try it you will see, this is an example of what it looks like: https://9to5google.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/chat-heads-facebook-messenger.jpg it doesn't pause the activity in the background so it isn't an activity or dialog. Although it is true that it is not added to the activity's view manager, this is possible when using a service's window manager.

Answer (score 2):

you may add these `setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` in your view

Comment: after that what change i need to make?

Comment: I can't seem to focus on anything else like EditText though?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still fairly new at this, but I'm trying to get similar functionality working. Here's what got it working for me (in Kotlin):

```
mOverlayView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.overlay_layout, null)

val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(         
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
    // This was the piece I was missing
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL 
        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, 
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
)

mWindowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
mWindowManager!!.addView(mOverlayView, params)

mOverlayView!!.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
mOverlayView!!.setOnKeyListener(object : View.OnKeyListener {
    override fun onKey(v: View?, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        // Custom code here...
        return true
    }
}
```